# How to make desktop shortcut to start command with custom title font and window borders

Tags: theme, .desktop, appearance

**Im Using Linux Mint 17.2 rafaela amd64 with cinnamon.** I have a couple old windows themes I downloaded and if I apply them with the system settings dialog I get this:

t[image: theme screenshot]

Which is great! Except **I only want the theme to be applied when I launch a shortcut**. For example the shortcut on the desktop *"Command Prompt"*, I found out how to make that shortcut launch Gnome terminal with a specific profile, but I want the **shortcut to also apply a specific theme, "window borders" theme, "controls" theme, and "icons" theme to the window launched**

Ive gotten the main theme to apply to a gedit window using [this method](https://urukrama.wordpress.com/2008/07/13/setting-a-custom-gtk-theme-for-specific-applications/):

```
GTK2_RC_FILES=/home/njord/.themes/old.gtkrc gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=oldWin
```

Where old.gtkrc is a custom theme that changes the default font to "Perfect DOS VGA 437 12", which is a font I want to use for the title bar as well.

The contents of old.gtkrc:

```
include "/home/njord/.themes/Windows\ Classic/gtk-2.0/gtkrc"

style "Perfect DOS VGA 437"
{
font_name = "Perfect DOS VGA 437 12"
}

widget_class "*" style "Perfect DOS VGA 437"
gtk-font-name = "Perfect DOS VGA 437 12"
```

**Basically, I want to use a different theme and title font for everything, but if I click a shortcut on the desktop launch a program with a custom:**

- Title Bar font
- Icon theme
- Window border (coloring of title bar and scrollbar etc.)
- "controls" theme (Changes dropdown menus style, buttons, etc.)

**Is this even possible? I think I might have to use something other than gtk2 (gtk3?). I've been using linux for a few years as my daily driver but I've never done this before.**

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!